# Post repetido no envio dos dados para o controller, como resolvo?

Tags: php, mvc, post, inserir

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema php mvc mas me deparei com esse problema no Create. O post está enviando multiplos dados repetidos não sei o porque está acontecendo isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu view create está assim

```
<form id="form1" action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>Products/Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button><br><br>
</form>
```

Tem apenas um campo porque estava testando, agora meu metodo no controller

```
public function Create(){
        $this->view->title = 'Novo';
        $this->view->dados = $_POST;

        if($_POST){
            //$this->view->errors = 'Não é um número';

            var_dump($_POST);

            $result = $this->Create($_POST['name']);

            if($result == true){
                $this->Redirect('Index');
            }

            $this->view->Render('Create');
            exit;
        }
        var_dump($_POST['name']);
        //$this->view->dados = $_POST;



        $this->view->Render('Create');
    }
```

Coloquei o var_dump foi ai que vi o porque dava erro no insert, ele ta multiplicando o post agora não entendo o porque.

Answer (score 1):

O post não está sendo enviado várias vezes, você que está lendo ele várias vezes, ao chamar uma função dentro da própria função, criando um loop infinito:

Você tem uma função `Create` e dentro dela chama `Create`:

```
public function Create(){
    //...
   $result = $this->Create($_POST['name']);
    //...
}
```

Do jeito que seu código está não tá fazendo muito sentido, observe que você cria a função `Create` mas ela não recebe nenhum parâmetro, porém dentro dela você chama a mesma função passando uma variável

Comment: Verdade, corrigi o erro, eu não estava conectando o model no método Create

Comment: Se resolveu o problema marque a resposta como correta :)